# what is the difference between local and global Rect method in android?

Tags: android, view, point

I have navigated through document pages but because of poor explanation i got nothing , what is the difference between methods below and when to use them ?

**getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect r)** ,

**getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect r, Point globalOffset)** ,

**getLocalVisibleRect(Rect r)**

What is the application and function of these methods ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, this is my knowledge about it. So maybe it will be wrong.
[image illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNK32.png)

Comment: what is the red and black rectangle ? can you explain a little bit

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explan. Red rectangle is your devices and black rectangle is your layout to display (for example is linearlayout, or button, or textview or anything else).